# Default font R plots changed into Arial

Tags: r, fonts, default, font-family

I've been working in R for a while, saving all my plots (pheatmaps, ggplots etc) into pdfs. The default font that R used was Helvetica Light. I usually load my R plots into Adobe and I can see the font family. However, I wanted to add some new fonts to my computer today, so I downloaded Helvetica bold and roman and just installed them on my Windows computer so they pop up in adobe.
However, all of a sudden my new plots in R are all being saved in Arial!
This is so frustrating, because I would need to redo my previous plots to get them all the same font, or change the Arial back to Helvetica default in R. But I cannot seem to be able to do the latter.
Does anyone know why this happened and how to change back to default Helvetica Light?

I already re-installed the fonts I installed, but R is still saving everything in Arial (also jpegs).
I also simply tried to define the font family when saving my ggplot but that also did not work.
I am using these codes to save my files:
`ggsave("X.pdf", plot = graph)`
or
`pheatmap (X, filename = "X.pdf")`

Cheers,
Sanne

Comment: What OS are you running under? I'm assuming macOS or Linux?

Comment: R's graphics devices allow you to specify the font family. Try passing `family = "Helvetica"` to ggsave. What does `postscriptFonts()$Helvetica` return?

Comment: You might have messed up your Helvetica .afm font files when installing additional fonts.